# Can i set remoteTimeOut to Infinity on TcpOutBoundgateway

Tags: spring-integration

I am using CachingClientConnectionFactory, How can i keep the connections alive, its closing out after default remoteTimeOut elapses, Can I set the remoteTimeOut to LONG.MAX_VALUE?

Thanks

```
 @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {  
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
        return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, connectionPoolSize);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel")
    public MessageHandler outboundGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(5_000);
        return tcpOutboundGateway;
    }
```

Comment: You can set it to long enough timeout, but I don't think `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + remoteTimeout)` would let us to use `Long.MAX_VALUE`. I see that the connection is closed when timeout on the reply happens, but better to ask why to use a gateway if there is not reply from the remote party? And why do you worry about those closed connections since their are reconnected on the next call if not enough resources in the cache?

Comment: The `remoteTimeout` only applies to a specific request/reply interaction - how long to wait for a reply. There is no mechanism to close the socket after some idle time; if the socket is being closed, it is most likely the server closing it. If you set it to a long time, the calling thread will block for that time.

Comment: @GaryRussell, Thanks for the comment, I will check from the server-side, When is the connection closed usually in the cache factory?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cache factory". With the `TcpNioClientConnectionFactory`, the default behavior is to open a single socket used by all sends; the socket is not closed until the factory is `stop()`ped - usually by stopping the outbound gateway in this case.

Comment: @GaryRussell, I mean AbstractClientConnectionFactory, If the single socket is used by all the sends, How does it match the request and response, Does it pick only the idle sockets to send the data?

Comment: They are single-threaded; concurrent sends are blocked until the socket is available. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#ip-gateways - you can use a `CachingClientConnectionFactory` to open multiple sockets for concurrency.

Comment: @GaryRussell, Yes I want it to single thread, I want concurrent send to be blocked until the socket is available; Can you confirm from the above the code if the concurrent sends are blocked?

Comment: @GaryRussell, I am able to read the response from the server but I am getting this message on the client-side "cannot correlate response - no pending reply for cached" after a minute, though the server is not sending any message back, From the server-side, I can see this message "Connection lost: " + handler.getSocket().getInetAddress()"  printed out in the log but not sent in the outputstream.

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in comments `no pending reply for cached`; that doesn't make sense `cached` should be a connection id (containing a UUID). If you are using the `CachingClientConnectionFactory` it would be `...Cached: <uuid>`. I suggest you ask a new question and post a minimal, complete, reproducible example app that shows the problem, so I can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes I want it to single thread, I want concurrent send to be blocked until the socket is available;

Yes; with that configuration, it will be single-threaded; concurrent requests will wait for up to `requestTimeout` to get access to the shared socket.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/4484c4da753096094e5b376411b94ac4ba2834c6/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/TcpOutboundGateway.java#L217

```java
try {
    haveSemaphore = acquireSemaphoreIfNeeded(requestMessage);
    connection = this.connectionFactory.getConnection();
    ...
```

The request that gets access to the socket then waits for up to `replyTimeout` for a reply. If it times out, the socket is closed, to avoid the next request getting this request's reply. The next request will get a new socket.

```
tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

That should be reduced to something more reasonable otherwise you could block forever if, for some reason, the server doesn't reply (but keeps the socket open).